# jQuery Textfill Problems

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I'm using the jquery textfill plugin from https://plugins.jquery.com/textfill/. Originally coded on my mac in chrome and everything's working fine. When I checked it on windows in chrome it's not filling the div all the way. I can see that it's functioning, it shows

```
<span style="font-size:5px;">
```

but it should be 9 to fill the container completely. When I tested the same page on the same computer in firefox it worked flawlessly. What could the problem be?

```
<header>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_1.5.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.textfill.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
function init() {
$('#bottomstufffinal').textfill({
    debug: true,
    maxFontPixels: 20
});
}

$(init);
</script>

</header>
```

body...

```
<div id="bottomstufffinal" style="width: 311px;height: 40px;">
<span><?  echo $list1; ?><br><? echo $list2; ?></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I've got a vaguely similar problem, where on Chrome on Android, the font size ends up being too big. It works correctly under Linux and Mac.

Comment: So the way I got mine working was 1) adding a minFontPixels: 10 to the init function and 2) removing the inline styling for the div - it's now just <div id="bottomstufffinal">. Hopefully that'll help!

Comment: Thanks. I eventually fixed my problem by changing the `white-space` CSS property. I think there's an issue with jquery-textfill not handling (admittedly crappy) CSS properly. I've filed it as such: https://github.com/jquery-textfill/jquery-textfill/issues/50

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

removing table-layout:fixed; works for me

Comment: Where was `table-layout: fixed`? In the jquery-textfill code? In the code in the question, somehow? Or just in your own code?